# STRING - DATE FORMAT BIGQUERY

Tags: google-bigquery

error is : Invalid timestamp: '2/17/2022'

Hi guys, Someone can help me to change STING (dd-mm-yyy) to a Date fomat (yyyy-mm-dd)?

thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
select parse_date('%m/%d/%Y', '2/17/2022'), parse_date('%m-%d-%Y', '2-17-2022')
```

with output

[image]